# Non-overlapping rectangles in CLP (CHR)

Tags: prolog, clp

I have a set of rectangles with varying coordinates for the top left corner of the rectangle and varying width/height.  For example, let's take a rectangle A with grounded variables: 1 for the X-coordinate (for the top left corner), 2 for Y, 1 for the width and 2 for the height.  Now rectangle B has variables which are not all grounded: 1 for X, [1,2] for Y, 2 for the width and [1,2] for the height.

Based on this information we should be able to tell that 2 is an impossible value for Y since it would cause the top left corners of both rectangles to be the same and so they would overlap. Y would then be grounded to 1. The same goes for the height: if the height is 2, then the bottom left corner of rectangle B will overlap with rectangle A, so only 1 is allowed.  With this information we were able to ground rectangle B through propagation.  But the problem for me is that I have many rectangles to consider and there are many options available.

I'm using CHR in SWI-Prolog for the implementation. Currently I have something like this (it's only a small part of the non-overlapping rectangles constraint that's implemented here):

```
% verify top left corner
rect(_,c(X,Y),s(W,H))\rect(Hint,c(_X,_Y),S)<=>
  number(X),number(Y),number(W),number(H),number(_X),\+ number(_Y),
  _X >= X, _X < X+W, Z is Y+H-1, numlist(Y,Z,NY), subtract(_Y,NY,NewY), \+ permutation(NewY,_Y) |
  rect(Hint,c(_X,NewY),S).
rect(_,c(X,Y),s(W,H))\rect(Hint,c(_X,_Y),S)<=>
  number(X),number(Y),number(W),number(H),\+ number(_X),number(_Y),
  _Y >= Y, _Y < Y+H, Z is X+W-1, numlist(X,Z,NX), subtract(_X,NX,NewX), \+ permutation(NewX,_X) |
  rect(Hint,c(NewX,_Y),S).

% better version of equals
permutation([], []).
permutation([H|T], R) :-
   permutation(T, X),
   delete(H, R, X).
permutation(X, Y) :- % in case of numbers instead of lists
   X == Y.
```

The rectangle on the left of the header is rectangle A and the one I simplify is rectangle B. If the X-coordinate is grounded (it's a number) but Y is not grounded (it's a list), then I try to remove all the impossible values for Y out of the list. Best case scenario only 1 element remains and we can ground Y as well. In the second simpagation rule I do the same: if we know the value for Y but not for X, we try to eliminate all the impossible values for X.

This is a lot of code for verifying if the top left corner of rectangle B is within rectangle A. I even simplified things already by assuming rectangle A is grounded first and this doesn't take into account the fact that the top left corner of A may be within rectangle B instead.  Things get a lot more complicated as I try to figure out the width and height propagation as there are so many combinations for rectangle placements and different overlap possibilities.  I feel quite overwhelmed thinking about all the possibilities I'd have to take into account.

I tried looking up algorithms for non-overlapping rectangles placements, but many assume I have complete information already. Unfortunately I don't have all grounded values and the whole point is for me to perform the propagation myself.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to tackle this in a strategic way?

Comment: Have you tried the CLP(FD) constraint [**`disjoint/2`**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clpfd%3Adisjoint2/1)? It should work also with variables.

Comment: Yea..  The thing about that is, this is part of an assignment I have to make and we are not allowed to use the CLP(FD) library.  I already implemented a solution with that library and it's very straightforward to implement it this way (using variables with a domain).  But I have to manually eliminate elements from lists. This seemingly makes the problem very complex.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's also kind of the reason why this functionality is already implemented in a library ;-)

Comment: @mat: We do need a chr-tag. Surprisingly, [tag:chr] is already taken.

Comment: even more pressing is a tag for `if_/3`. in actuality, what about `mif/3`: monotonic if?